# Zuul Proxy not able to route, resulting in com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error

Tags: netflix-zuul

I have simple services as:

transactions-core-service and transactions-api-service.

transactions-api-service invokes transactions-core-service to return a list of transactions. transactions-api-service is enabled with hystrix command.

Both are registered in Eureka server with below services ids:

```
TRANSACTIONS-API-SERVICE    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 192.168.2.12:transactions-api-service:8083
TRANSACTIONS-CORE-SERVICE   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 192.168.2.12:transactions-core-service:8087
```

Below is Zuul server:

```
@SpringBootApplication

@Controller

@EnableZuulProxy

public class ZuulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

Zuul Configurations:

```
===============================================

info:
  component: Zuul Server

server:
  port: 8765

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    transactions-api-service: 
    path: transactions/accounts/**
    serviceId: transactions-api-service

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG

===============================================
```

When I try to invoke transactions-api-service with url (`http://localhost:8765/transactions/accounts/123/transactions/786`) I get Zuul Exception:

> 2016-02-13 11:29:29.050  WARN 4936 --- [nio-8765-exec-1]
>   o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
>
> com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:131)
>   ~[spring-cloud-net flix-core-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3]
>           at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:76)
>   ~[spring-cloud-netflix- core-1.1.0.M3.jar:1.1.0.M3] ......

If I invoke the transactions-api-service individually (with `localhost /accounts/123/transactions/786`), it works fine.

Am I missing any configurations on Zuul?

Comment: I have added in my gateway service application.properties file and it’s work

Answer (score 11):

You need to change zuul execution timeout by adding this property in  *application.yml* of zuul server:

```
# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Please refer to this thread on netflix issues: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/321

Comment: You'll still get this error even if this is set.

Answer (score 10):

Faced same issue. In my case, zuul was using service discovery. As a solution, below configuration worked like a charm.

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
```

Reference to the property usage is [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_zuul_timeouts).

Comment: This wont work still get error

Answer (score 4):

You have an incorrect indentation. Instead of:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    transactions-api-service: 
    path: transactions/accounts/**
    serviceId: transactions-api-service
```

It should be:

```
zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    transactions-api-service: 
      path: transactions/accounts/**
      serviceId: transactions-api-service
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to avoid 500 error

hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=1000000

zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=10000

zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=1000000

Comment: works with:
host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 60000
    socket-timeout-millis: 60000

Answer (score 0):

In case if your Zuul gateway uses discovery service for service lookup in that case you can disable the hystrix timeout or increase the hysterix timeout as below :

```
# Disable Hystrix timeout globally (for all services)
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled: false

#To disable timeout foror particular service,
hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.timeout.enabled: false

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (globally)
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000

# Increase the Hystrix timeout to 60s (per service)
hystrix.command.<serviceName>.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with zuul server, it got resolved with below property
Let's say you have 2 clients clientA and clientB,
so for clientA, `spring.application.name=clientA` and `server.port=1111`
for clientB  `spring.application.name=clientB` and `server.port=2222` in there respective application.propeties files.
You want to connect this 2 servers to ZuulServer which is running on port 8087.
add below properties in you ZuulServer application.properties file

> spring.application.name=gateway-service
> eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
> eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
> eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
> clientA.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:1111
> clientB.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:2222
>
> server.port=8087

Note: I am using Eureka Client with my Zuul Server. you can skip that part. Adding this solution in case its helpful for someone.